# write scala code for calculating distance to and from our given point

Tags: scala, apache-spark

we have four columns.we need to calculate the distance means as per our 
 requirement.need to write the spark scala code and store in 
 dataframe

```
 country,state,speed,time
  c1,s1,25kph,8h
  c1,s2,5kph,12h
  c2,s3,35kph,9h
  c2,s5,53kph,7.5h
  c3,s5,82kph,8h
  c4,s6,35kph,7h
  c5,s7,95kph,6h
  c2,s3,65kph,11h
  c1,s2,8kph,32h
```

like this, we have 1000 different rows in a CSV file

we need to calculate the distance means as per our 
     requirement.need to write the spark scala code and store in 
     dataframe.write a spark scala code to find the distance using speed 
     and time of given country and state from c2,s3 to c4 s6 one trip or 
     from any starting point to another ending point, need to calculate 
     the distance further from  c4,s6 to c2,s3 (it then completes a round 
     trip)

Comment: No offense but that sounds like a homework. What have you done so far? Where do you struggle?

Comment: If you have problems with the math: If you go 8h with 25kph (kilometers per hour) The distance you traveled is 8*25 [km].

Comment: i have written the code for calculating the distance from one point to last but i am not able to calculate it from a particular record to another record.

Comment: i have written this example to explain better what i actually want but i am working some other things, i changed the attributes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the data as per your given format to be copied into as text file say `timedist.txt`, and assuming the file in the current directory of scala, the regular expression below utilised in reading the file into  `df` (`List of tuples` of type `(String,String,Double,Double,Double) along with distances calculated for each record`).

```
val p = """(.{2}),(.{2}),(\d+\.?\d*)kph,(\d+\.?\d*)h""".r
val td = scala.io.Source.fromFile("timedist.txt").getLines.map(_.trim()).toList

 val df = td.map(x=>{var p(c,s,speed,distance)=x;
      (c,s,speed.toDouble,distance.toDouble,speed.toDouble*distance.toDouble)})
```

Now, this function takes `df` as a parameter along with two `Int` parameters representing `fromRecord` and `toRecord` (`fromRecord < toRecord`)and calculates two-way distance(`roundtrip`).

```
 def calcDist(fromRecord:Int,toRecord:Int,df:List[(String,String,Double,Double,Double)]) = {
 df.map(_._5).zipWithIndex.filter(x=>x._2>=(fromRecord-1) && x._2<=(toRecord-1)).map(_._1).sum*2
 }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val p = """(.{2}),(.{2}),(\d+\.?\d*)kph,(\d+\.?\d*)h""".r
p: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.{2}),(.{2}),(\d+\.?\d*)kph,(\d+\.?\d*)h

scala> var td = scala.io.Source.fromFile("timedist.txt").getLines.map(_.trim()).toList
td: List[String] = List(c1,s1,25kph,8h, c1,s2,5kph,12h, c2,s3,35kph,9h, c2,s5,53kph,7.5h, c3,s5,82kph,8h, c4,s6,35kph,7h, c5
,s7,95kph,6h, c2,s3,65kph,11h, c1,s2,8kph,32h)

scala> val df = td.map(x=>{var p(c,s,speed,distance)=x;
        (c,s,speed.toDouble,distance.toDouble,speed.toDouble*distance.toDouble)})
df: List[(String, String, Double, Double, Double)] = List((c1,s1,25.0,8.0,200.0), (c1,s2,5.0,12.0,60.0), (c2,s3,35.0,9.0,315
.0), (c2,s5,53.0,7.5,397.5), (c3,s5,82.0,8.0,656.0), (c4,s6,35.0,7.0,245.0), (c5,s7,95.0,6.0,570.0), (c2,s3,65.0,11.0,715.0)
, (c1,s2,8.0,32.0,256.0))
```

Now this will give `roundtrip` distance from `3rd record to 6th record`.

```
scala> calcDist(3,6,df)
res139: Double = 3227.0

scala>
```

If the List `df` is to be converted into a dataframe;

```
df.toDF("Country", "State", "speed","time","distance")
```

**In scala REPL:**

```
scala> df.toDF("Country", "State", "speed","time","distance").show
+-------+-----+-----+----+--------+
|Country|State|speed|time|distance|
+-------+-----+-----+----+--------+
|     c1|   s1| 25.0| 8.0|   200.0|
|     c1|   s2|  5.0|12.0|    60.0|
|     c2|   s3| 35.0| 9.0|   315.0|
|     c2|   s5| 53.0| 7.5|   397.5|
|     c3|   s5| 82.0| 8.0|   656.0|
|     c4|   s6| 35.0| 7.0|   245.0|
|     c5|   s7| 95.0| 6.0|   570.0|
|     c2|   s3| 65.0|11.0|   715.0|
|     c1|   s2|  8.0|32.0|   256.0|
+-------+-----+-----+----+--------+
```

In this case, it is necessary to find distances from `one record` to `another record` and it will be handy to have a `record column` as `first item` in the converted `dataframe` preferably. First, the list `df` is to be converted as below:

```
val dfWithRecordNos = df.zipWithIndex.map(x=>(x._2+1,x._1)).map{case (a,(b,c,d,e,f))=>(a,b,c,d,e,f)}
```

**Then in Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val dfWithRecordNos = df.zipWithIndex.map(x=>(x._2+1,x._1)).map{case (a,(b,c,d,e,f))=>(a,b,c,d,e,f)}
dfWithRecordNos: List[(Int, String, String, Double, Double, Double)] = List((1,c1,s1,25.0,8.0,200.0), (2,c1,s2,5.0,12.0,60.0
), (3,c2,s3,35.0,9.0,315.0), (4,c2,s5,53.0,7.5,397.5), (5,c3,s5,82.0,8.0,656.0), (6,c4,s6,35.0,7.0,245.0), (7,c5,s7,95.0,6.0
,570.0), (8,c2,s3,65.0,11.0,715.0), (9,c1,s2,8.0,32.0,256.0))
```

Now, the `calcDist` will be as below:

```
 def calcDist(fromRecord:Int,toRecord:Int,dfWithRecordNos:List[(Int,String,String,Double,Double,Double)]) = {
 dfWithRecordNos.filter(x=>x._1>=fromRecord && x._1<=toRecord).map(_._6).sum*2
}
```

**and in Scala REPL:**

```
scala> calcDist(3,6,dfWithRecordNos)
res12: Double = 3227.0



scala> dfWithRecordNos.toDF("Record","Country", "State", "speed","time","distance").show
+------+-------+-----+-----+----+--------+
|Record|Country|State|speed|time|distance|
+------+-------+-----+-----+----+--------+
|     1|     c1|   s1| 25.0| 8.0|   200.0|
|     2|     c1|   s2|  5.0|12.0|    60.0|
|     3|     c2|   s3| 35.0| 9.0|   315.0|
|     4|     c2|   s5| 53.0| 7.5|   397.5|
|     5|     c3|   s5| 82.0| 8.0|   656.0|
|     6|     c4|   s6| 35.0| 7.0|   245.0|
|     7|     c5|   s7| 95.0| 6.0|   570.0|
|     8|     c2|   s3| 65.0|11.0|   715.0|
|     9|     c1|   s2|  8.0|32.0|   256.0|
+------+-------+-----+-----+----+--------+


scala>
```

Comment: thanks its valuable , and how we can do this on dataframe? any function supporting this

Comment: You can just use the `toDF` method on the generated `List[(String,String,Double,Double,Double)]` as shown above. Depending on your config you may need to run` import sqlContext.implicits._`.